# Comparing Mysql Datetime with Twig Date()

Tags: php, twig

I have some variable named `setting.graduate_start` and `setting.graduate_end`. Both have MySQL DATETIME format like `2020-08-05 11:55:00`.
All I want is tp display a menu if today is between **`setting.graduate_start`**  and **`setting.graduate_end`**.

So I wrote the code like this:

```
 {% if date(setting.graduate_start) > date() and date(setting.graduate_end) < date()%}
      <li><a href="/graduation">Graduation</a></li>
 {% endif %}
```

`setting.graduate_start` is `2020-08-05 11:55:00` and `setting.graduate_end` is `2020-08-10 12:00:00`, so, when today is `2020-08-06` the list element is supposed to be displayed but it wasn't.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date()`, in Twig, [is a filter to format date](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/date.html), alone [it doesn't do anything](https://twigfiddle.com/sfd9el).

If you want the current date, you'll need to use `'now' | date()`, but that will still not give the format you expect.

But as prompted in the documentation:

> The format specifier is the same as supported by [date](https://secure.php.net/date), except when the filtered data is of type [DateInterval](https://secure.php.net/DateInterval), when the format must conform to [DateInterval::format](https://secure.php.net/DateInterval.format) instead.

<sup>*Source: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/date.html#date*</sup>

So with all this together:

```
{% if 'now' | date('Y-m-d H:i:s') > setting.graduate_start | date('Y-m-d H:i:s') and 'now' | date('Y-m-d H:i:s') < setting.graduate_end | date('Y-m-d H:i:s')  %}
  <li><a href="/graduation">Graduation</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

Renders your link [as it should](https://twigfiddle.com/sfd9el/3).